# more than h1 inline with grid template areas

Tags: html, css

hi all i am new to html and css i got a simple question:
i wrote this html code

```
<div class="ourtlimg">
            <div class="name1"><h1>Daniel Martin</h1><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.<br>Libero aperiam commodi similique labore neque dicta.</p></div>
            <div class="name2"><h1>Craig Nobel</h1><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.<br>Libero aperiam commodi similique labore neque dicta.</p></div>
            <div class="name3"><h1>Nicole Mark</h1><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.<br>Libero aperiam commodi similique labore neque dicta.</p></div>

        </div>
```

i made a grid-template-area for the class name1,name2,name3 in 6times 1fr repeat as{port1 port1 port2 port2 port3 port3}to display in one line and when i give each class one of three grid areas it display like the image below.I want to display them in one line with the grid system can you help please.I want them across the page instead of down the page[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9IhF.png)

i added this css for the wrapper:

```
.wrapper{
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(6,1fr);
grid-template-areas:
'header header header header header header'
'navbar navbar navbar navbar navbar navbar'
'welsec welsec welsec welsec welsec welsec'
'tlinfo tlinfo tlinfo tlinfo tlinfo tlinfo'
'port1 port1 port2 port2 port3 port3'
;
}
```

and this for the classes in code:

```
.name1{
grid-area: port1;
float: left;
}
.name2{
grid-area: port2;
float: left;
}
.name3{
grid-area: port3;
float: left;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean, you want them across the page instead of down the page?  The easy way to do that is with a \<table\>, but that is apparently uncool today.  The other way is to use `float:left` in the CSS.

Comment: Do you mean, you want them across the page instead of down the page?YES

Comment: Tim Roberts it did not work with float:left

Comment: Then you did it wrong.  Please modify your question to show the code you have now.

Comment: @AmrElnagdy Please update your question with the code snippets formatted correctly.

Comment: updated the question @TimRoberts

Comment: The suggestion below is better than mine.  Throw out the grid stuff, use `display:inline`.

Comment: I encourage you to do two things, first (important), use just one `h1` tag per page, second (advice/tip), you can use a table to achieve that, it'll be easier.

Comment: Hi, just note that h1 shouldn't be used multiple times on a single page. Check the mdn for more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements

Answer (score 1):

This css code will do all the work =)

```css
.ourtlimg {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="ourtlimg">
  <div class="name1">
    <h1>Daniel Martin</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.<br>Libero aperiam commodi similique labore neque dicta.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="name2">
    <h1>Craig Nobel</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.<br>Libero aperiam commodi similique labore neque dicta.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="name3">
    <h1>Nicole Mark</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.<br>Libero aperiam commodi similique labore neque dicta.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: p {
    display: inline;
}

h1 {
    display: inline;
}

Comment: i am sorry sir but nothing happened still the same

Comment: i want them to be in one line sir

Comment: I think now what is needed